# npm unexpected token / in config.json at position 98

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, npm

I have seen several unexpected token errors related to npm but this one is yet again unique to me. I could not find any similar issues posted by others. My config file just has connection objects to my local mongodb, rabbitmq "amqp", wordpress plugin and mysql DB.

Could anyone help me with this error in case they've seen it before?

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\livetrader\chat\node_modules\nconf\lib\nconf\stores\file.js:160
throw new Error("Error parsing your configuration file: [" + this.file + ']: ' + ex.message);
^

Error: Error parsing your configuration file:     
[C:\xampp\htdocs\livetrader\chat/config.json]: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 98
```

Updating this post with the config.json file referenced in this error

```
{
  "port": 1337,
  "mongoose": {
    "uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/livetrader"
  },

  "amqp":{
    "uri": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672",
    "queue": "TickData"
  },

  "sql":{
    "host":"localhost",
    "database":"db_main",
    "user":"root",
    "password":""
  },

  "wp":{
    "host":"http://forextrader.dev",
    "LOGGED_IN_KEY":"MY_LOGGED_IN_KEY",
    "LOGGED_IN_SALT":"MY_LOGGED_IN_SALT",
    "prefix":"wp_",
    "avatarPath":"http://localhost/livetrader/wp-content/uploads/avatars",
    "myCreedApi":"MY_API_KEY"
  },

  "guest":{
   "cookie_name": "trading-forex-guest",
   "ttl": 180
 }
}
```

Updating the back-end config path

"use strict";

```
var nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.argv()
    .env()
    .file({
        file: process.cwd() + '/config.json'
    });

module.exports = nconf;
```

Comment: We'll need to see a copy of the configuration file, if we are to detect the problem. **Take care to remove all secret keys and passwords before posting it**. The details you posted about the error are not necessary, just knowing `Unexpected character / at position 98` is enough. You can remove the rest from the question =)

Comment: Right, so, i think your problem is in config.json at position 98. There's probably something wrong around the \ character.

Comment: @Kevin B right but there's no \ character that's apparent. I will post the config file contents

Comment: Thanks @slezica I should have truncated the unnecessary messages. Will do so and post the config file contents without secret keys

Comment: @slezica please review the config.json file

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is property formatted. `JSON.parse()` takes it, no problem. Character 98 is not a slash, either.

There is, however, a suspicious slash in your path:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\livetrader\chat/config.json
```

The final slash is unix-style, not windows-style. Could that be causing the problem?

If that's not it, you must be reading the wrong file, or passing it the wrong way to a function. Try using `console.log` to figure out what exactly is reaching `JSON.parse()`.

Giving objects to `JSON.parse()` can cause unexpected errors, since `.toString()` is invoked. For example:

```
> JSON.parse({a:1})
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

> ({a:1}).toString()
'[object Object]'
```

So, to recap, you must be:

1. Reading the wrong file
2. Passing an object that's not a `String` to `JSON.parse()`
3. Having a strange problem with the inverted slash in the path

Comment: strange indeed. This was not the case earlier. I am not sure what changed, will investigate further but could you please take a look at the config.json path it has the correct slash in the path.